# My header image won't show

Tags: html, css

I am making a small website (school project), but my background won't appear at all! I have tried moving the image/path, adding it to the body instead. Is there something wrong with the code, or something else?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
a {
  color: hsla(37, 39%, 72%, 1.00);
  text-decoration: none;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.header {
  background: url(img/background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">

  <section class="logo">&Bscr;</section>

  <section class="nav-icon">
    <span class="icon"></span>
  </section>

  <section class="nav-overlay"></section>

  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation__ul">
      <li><a href="#">Banan</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Eple</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Druer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pære</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Appelsin</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<main class="main-content">

</main>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The path of img is correct?

Comment: Your header is taking up the entire screen because of your CSS height property for the header. That may be your issue.

Comment: your code work fine. see jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u7tzptk6/

Comment: Weird how it works in jsfiddle, but not in my browser... i am making a navigation menu for the site, thus the header taking up the screen.

Comment: @malikaasen It has to be your folder structure in that case.

Comment: @TristandeJager i tried changing folders and adding the image in the folder where the css is, but it still won't show

Comment: If the code works in jsfiddle try clearing your browser cache...

Comment: If `img` and `css` is in different folders, then you need to access root directory, by using `../` in your case `../img/background.jpg`

Comment: tried it, still won't change, also  tried viewing it in another browser @Benediah

Comment: tried copying the whole root directory, still no change @AbhishekPandey

Comment: Make sure you are using same `Filename extension` `.jpg`

Comment: Got it! @AbhishekPandey for some odd reason i had to change it to .jpg.jpg

Comment: Maybe your image is really named background.jpg.jpg and you are using an OS that thinks it's a good idea to hide the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try and change the background tag to background-image

```
background-image: url(img/background.jpg);
```

Comment: You are kidding right. `background` is a shorthand for any of the background properties. @shreyas

Comment: I know that. He can just try

Comment: Brother you didn't had any idea otherwise you wouldn't have posted such a silly answer.@shreyas

Comment: Nice English brother. And I know very well background is a short hand property of background properties. I posted that answer as there might be bugs temporarily with the browser and this had happened to me 2-3 times as well. I didn't say you have to do that only, I'm just telling to try it out cause it worked for me.

Comment: You still working in 90's. Its 2k16 brother. Grow up.

Comment: Bro am done. Work on your tech and grow your rating.